# Regroup y-axis field by day, week, months in OpenERP V7

Tags: graph, openerp-7

I'd like to know how to regroup the Y-Axis of graphs in openERP v7 by day, month, year.
I already try this but openERP regroup by months.

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="id_view_contact">
            <field name="name">test.base.graph.view1</field>
            <field name="model">test.base</field>
            <field name="type">graph</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <graph string="contacts" type="bar" >
                    <field name="create_date"  group="False" />
                    <field name="temperature" />
                </graph>

            </field>
        </record>
```

Is there any way to regroup the y-axis by hour, day, week, year?

Comment: Is that possible using Filters?

Comment: I can't find solution yet, any body have an idea?

Comment: Any help to resolve this problem